# Calculate surface area of a F using the surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, surface-integrals

## Task

Given:
$$F := \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid (x,y) \in W,z=f(x,y)\}$$

Calculate the surface area using the surface integral:

$i) \; f(x,y) := x+y \;\; and \;\; W := [12,31] \times [2014,2015]$
$ii) \; f(x,y) := \cos(x) \;\; and \;\; W := [0,\pi] \times [0,2\pi]$

$$$$

## My Calculations

$i)$

$$
\vec{\phi}:[12,31]\times[2014,2015] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, \; \vec{\phi}\left(u,v\right)=
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v\\
u+v
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\left\|\frac{\partial\vec{\phi}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial\vec{\phi}}{\partial v}\right\|
=
\left\|
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\|
=
\left\|
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
-1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\|
=
\sqrt{3}
$$

$$o(F) = \iint_F 1 \; d\sigma = \iint_F\left\|\frac{\partial \vec{\phi}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial \vec{\phi}}{\partial v}\right\|d(u,v)$$
$$ = \int_{2014}^{2015} \int_{12}^{31} \sqrt{3} \; dudv = 1 \cdot \sqrt{3} \cdot 19 = 19\sqrt{3}$$

I tried to calculate this roughly via vectors lenghts and the result was $o(F)=\sqrt{2} \cdot 19\sqrt{2} = 38$, one of those two calculations must therefore be wrong, and assuming I did the vector math right it seems I'm doing something wrong in the surface integrals.

$$$$

$ii)$

$$
\vec{\phi}:[0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, \; \vec{\phi}\left(u,v\right)=
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v\\
\cos u
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\left\|\frac{\partial\vec{\phi}}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial\vec{\phi}}{\partial v}\right\|
=
\left\|
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-\sin u
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\right\|
=
\left\|
\begin{pmatrix}
\sin u\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\|
=
\sqrt{\sin^2 u + 1}
$$

$$o(F) = \iint_F 1 \; d\sigma = \iint_F\left\|\frac{\partial \vec{\phi}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial \vec{\phi}}{\partial v}\right\|d(u,v)$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{\sin^2 u + 1} \; dvdu = 2\pi \cdot \int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\sin^2 u + 1} \; dvdu = \; ???$$

It seems there is no good solution for this integral, therefore I must be doing something wrong because such tasks will most likely be solvable.

## Question

My suspicion is that my parametric representations of F ($\phi$) are wrong. It seems that one cannot transform them into spherical or polar coordinates (all my previous tasks were transformable, that's why I'm struggling) and thus I'm wondering what to do in such a case.

Comment: Is this still open or have you solved it?

Comment: @AlecTeal It's still open, you found a mistake?

Comment: I have noticed from your recent questions (surface area of a sphere) that you don't really know what's going on, so I have written a huge but detailed answer about how to do questions like this.

Comment: Are you sure it's cos?

Comment: @AlecTeal do you mean $f(x,y) := \cos(x)$ in the given task? Yes I'm sure. I might not have put up the right questions, the problem I'm having is getting a correct parametric representation of F for i) and ii).

Comment: MUCH much better notation, well done! You've actually buggered up the integration for the first question (you've forgotten to do the outer integral!), great progress but a few tips to get it really perfect: No arrow above your vectors, this is taught when you are young because they want you to see "this is a vector, not a number" but at this level it is usually reserved for vector fields - something you'll be integrating later. Also remember here you're using $x$ and $y$, I used $u$ and $v$ just to demonstrate more than $x$ and $y$ exist, but you have used $u$ and $v$ correctly! Good work!

Comment: @AlecTeal I'm glad we seem to be talking on the same topic now, but I am in fact already been taught how to integrate over vector field (no trouble there) and since $\phi$ is in fact a vector valued function there should be no problem using the vector arrows, or is there? Also the I did not forget about the outer integral:
To my understanding there is no $y$ or $v$ involved (whatever you may call it) the integral is calculated simply by calculating $2015 - 2014 = 1$ and that changes nothing when multiplied with anything, since it's the neutral element of the multiplication.

Comment: I've posted my solution and you are right, 2015-2014 is of course 1! I forgot the limits when I worked out mine (I used x1,x2,y1 and y2) and just remembered "big number" so it seemed low! Anyway great notation! Oh also, vector valued and vector field are different things, for example gravity is a vector field you might integrate over (a path along this field) this integral is naturally $\int g.df$ - g dot-product with a small part of our path, this is of course not nice to use, and multiplying by $\frac{dt}{dt}$ is much nicer! $\int g(f(t)).\frac{df}{dt}dt$ is the result.

Comment: Just noticed, $d(u,v)$ - this is a VERY not obvious notation (distance, metric spaces?) and one I have never seen used, use $dA$ because that's what you're integrating with respect to, a small bit of area. Only put $dudv$ (or $dxdy$ or whatever) in when you are going to commit to the order of integration! That is $dydx$ means your inner integral is with respect to y and done first. I GTG now.

Comment: @AlecTeal It seems you are trying to make me use your prefered notation here. As I said I'm from Europe and you seem to be from America (other dot product formula and whatnot, note that I didn't say you should change anything on that, I just roll with your notation because I know what you mean and that's all there is no notation, making obvious what you are trying to do). Also using $dA$ or $d(u,v)$ is the same thing, you are only saying what you want to integrating over without order. Anyways I'd like to drop the discussion about notation because that's not really the problem IMHO.

Comment: I'm UK and I don't do lectures, instead I read a lot of books and see a lot of different notations used, I have never seen d(u,v) used in any book. I'm teaching you a good intuitive notation, you are arguing against using x and y for x and y coordinates. I would not try to teach you unless I had full confidence in what I wrote, I planned this answer carefully, I am not another student saying "here's what I do" I'm teaching, completely with no iffy or fuzzy bits, now $\int_Hd\sigma$ and $\iint_Hd\sigma$ there's a choice, u,v for x and y, vector field symbols where you don't have a field, comeon

Answer (score 5):

Okay it is ABUNDANTLY clear you are not very confident with notation (as it is awful) so I shall teach you all you need to know about doing stuff on surfaces.

Lets tackle this intuitively, I will assume you are happy with the area of a parallelogram being related to the vector cross product, if not it is literally by definition (remember the sin rule for area of a triangle, it's that) so be happy with that, it is important.

**We know that:** $\|u\times v\|=\|u\|\|v\|\sin(\theta)=$ area of parallelogram with edges the vectors $u$ and $v$

Idea: We want to break the surface, call it $H$ (I choose H because why not) into little chunks, then sum over those chunks, like with all integrals, we shall write this: (where $d\sigma$ is a small chunk and H our surface)$$\iint_Hd\sigma$$
Don't worry about this too much, it's notation, use what helps, some authors write $\int_Hd\sigma$ instead, I use two integrals to emphasise (read: not let me forget) that I am integrating over a surface.

Picture time![image]

So we take a point $f(x,y)$ and we go $\delta x$ in the x direction, ending up at $f(x+\delta x,y)$ - already you should be thinking of the gradient, we are approximating the surface at $f(x,y)$ with a parallelogram, anyway, this gives us the double-marked line, the single one is by going $\delta y$ in the $y$ direction.

Notice the point $E$, the dotted line shows that this is quite far above the surface at this point, this is an approximation after all (which is why I have used $\delta$s) - anyway using the formula above the area of this parallelogram (which is $\delta\sigma$ - our small chunk of surface) is $\|u\times v\|$ where u and v are the different lines that make the parallelogram, as I have written on the diagram.

$$\delta\sigma = \|(f(x+\delta x,y)-f(x,y))\times(f(x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y))\|$$

Remember the definition of partial-derivatives, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{\delta x\rightarrow 0}(\frac{f(x+\delta x,y)-f(x,y)}{\delta x})$ this means $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\approx\frac{f(x+\delta x,y)-f(x,y)}{\delta x}$ (is approx. for small $\delta x$) thus:

$\delta x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\approx f(x+\delta x,y)-f(x,y)$ and $\delta y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\approx f(x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y)$ by the same logic.

So:

$$\delta\sigma = \|(f(x+\delta x,y)-f(x,y))\times(f(x,y+\delta y)-f(x,y))\|\approx\|\delta x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\delta y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|$$

Recall the definition of cross product, $\|u\times v\|=\|u\|\|v\|\sin(\theta)$, if we have scalars $a,b\ge 0$ (which we do, we have $\delta x$ and $\delta y$) then $\|au\times bv\|=\|au\|\|bv\|\sin(\theta)=|a|\|u\||b|\|v\|\sin(\theta)=ab\|u\|\|v\|\sin(\theta)=ab\|u\times v\|$

So:

$$\delta\sigma \approx\|\delta x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\delta y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|=\delta x\delta y\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|$$

Taking limits (as $\delta x,\delta y$ tend towards zero, leaving the approximation to get equality) we see that:

$$d\sigma=dxdy\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|$$

Now $\iint_Hd\sigma=\iint_R\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|dA$ where here $dA$ is a small chunk of area, in our case $dA=dxdy=dydx$, here $R$ means "Range" or "Region", it is what we will integrate over.

**Why $dA$?**

Lets take a function $f$ defined on some region $R$ and the integral $\iint_RfdA$, there are many ways to look at R, we could use cartesian coordinates, $x$ and $y$, or we could use polar coordinates $r,\theta$ say, suppose we take the circle of radius 10, we could define this as $R=\{(x,y)|-10<x<10\text{ and }-\sqrt{100-x^2}<y<\sqrt{100-x^2}\}$ or $R=\{(r,\theta)|r<10\}$

These are the same region, also the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is the same as $f(r,\theta)=r^2$, as you can see for the parabaloid $x^2+y^2$ we can use several coordinates, this is what manifolds (in essence) studies, you can pick several coordinates and arrive at the same thing.

**Back on topic**

Notice that by using $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and the same for y, I imply $dA$ will be in $dxdy$ form, so if our region is best given in polar coordinates, I'd have to convert it to Cartesian and work with that, this transformation is called "The Jacobian" and will come later for you. So let us give one general statement of surface area:

$$\iint_Hd\sigma=\iint_R\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\|dA$$ where $u$ and $v$ are not degenerate, that is they are not vectors of the same direction (as then we wouldn't have a parallelogram)

It is trivial that in the cartesian plane $dA=dxdy=dydx$ - any 5 year old can tell you the area of a rectangle is width times height.

Notice I didn't write $\iint_Hd\sigma=\iint_R\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|dxdy$ earlier, you're probably wondering why, this notation makes it clear that I am looking at R in a cartesian system (I have x and ys) the answer is personal preference, I do not like this because it fixes order (x first in this case) yet we have not given the integral limits in this case. Also the x and y appearing in the partials already imply I am looking at cartesian coordinates, I do not want to say doing the x integral first, hence $dA$

Using the circle example again with the parabaloid (call this parabaloid H) $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2=r^2=f(r,\theta)$, over the circle of radius 10, we can write:

$\iint_Hd\sigma=\iint_R\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|dA$
$=\int^{10}_{-10}\int^{\sqrt{100-x^2}}_{-\sqrt{100-x^2}}\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|dydx$
$=\int^{10}_{-10}\int^{\sqrt{100-y^2}}_{-\sqrt{100-y^2}}\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|dxdy$

Or we can go to polar!

$=\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{10}_{0}\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\|rdrd\theta$

Now the order of $dx$ and $dy$ matters, which is why I write it!

So where did $rdrd\theta=dA$ come from?

[image]

You can see in the first picture that $\delta A$ looks nothing like a rectangle, however lets make our approximation better by looking at a smaller $\delta\theta$, (the second picture), now $\delta A$ looks nice and rectangular, I have used an arc through $\delta\theta$ of radius $r$ has length $r\delta\theta$ to get these, notice though we have two approximations, (we can use $r\delta\theta$ or $(r+\delta r)\delta\theta$ for the "height" of the rectangle), in the latter one we have a $(\delta r)^2$, for tiny $\delta r$ if we square it we will get an even tinier number (think about 0.1, $0.1^2=0.01$ which is so tiny we can discard) meaning the approximations agree with each other, if we take the limit as the deltas tend towards zero we arrive at $dA=rdrd\theta$ as I claimed.

**End of explanation**

Triple-integrals (where I use $dV$ rather than $dA$ to mean "small chunk of volume") follow this same logic, so this is a good notation to adopt and understanding it makes exams easy!

**Additional things to notice**

There is one other approach you could use, a picture is worth a thousand words (and there are enough words here!)

We can take a chunk of the tangent plane, and map it onto the unit square, notice that the unit square has area 1 and this is a linear transform, so you say "at (x,y) 1 unit of area is worth $\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|$ units of surface, so we can say $dxdy$ units of area is worth $dxdy\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\|$ units of surface area, we can integrate over x,y already (this is our region, or range, R)

I've tried to draw part of the surface of a small ball, you can see how the parallelagram who's surface area is worth 1 unit of region area (at x,y) is a crappy approximation to the ball, however take a small chunk of it (I've written $dS$ I should have written $\delta A$) the small chunk that maps to ($\delta\sigma$ (I should have written this, I wrote $d\sigma)) is a good approximation.

[image]

Please do tell me what you think, also I'll work out the exact answers (without working - just so you can check) after dinner, I've not forgotten, I love being able to check I am right, so I promise to give you exact answers after dinner! I'd love to know what you think, I want to teach and would love feedback on this "lecture" length answer!

---

**As promised, solutions**

I did these last night but I wanted to wait for you to read this first, here is an answer in full.

As for the second one, I'll ask a friend today but I'm having a difficult time integrating $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)+1}$ and this is backed up by its shape, I suspect it might be a special/nice case because of the $\pi$ in the integral limits, but I'll keep you posted.

[image]

Comment: Well I took those notations right from an accepted answer on a similar question about surface integrals, I wonder how this might be wrong. And beforehand I was told my notation was hard to read, is there any real problem with it being wrong? I think you guys (maybe America vs. Europe) might just have another default notation, but if it means the same there is no problem with any of those notations is there?

Also I found it quite offensive that you say I have no idea what I'm talking about. In my only other question about this topic I've made a simple mistake forgetting a square root.

Comment: The one real problem I'm having is getting a correct representation of F to insert into the formula, I already know all of the things you said, maybe it's of use for future readers, but that did not really help me personally. I'll update the question to make this clearer and tidy things up a bit.

Comment: @Alec Teal, there were a few word choices that maybe weren't the best as far as presentation courtesy (any 5 year old can tell you). I'm confident you aren't trying to be rude, it's just hard to tell tone on the internet, so FYI for the future. Mathematical content looked good, so I +1'd it anyway. It's a good post, I like it. :)

Comment: @L1me sorry I just assumed it was implicit, H (our surface) is a set of points given by a function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow H$, like $F(u,v)=(u,v,f(u,v))$, so to take an $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to it's surface you have $F(u,v)=(u,v,f(u,v))$ - I did work out the answers but $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)+1}$ has no nice solution, so I'm working on it

Comment: @FundThmCalculus I meant it as a way of saying "This is the natural definition of area" because one might ask "why do we define it in terms of Cartesian, why do we turn dxdy into rdrd$\theta$, why not start in polar, the answer: we define area naturally on the Cartesian plane" - can you think of a better way of saying it?

Comment: Also damn, my writing looks like that of a 5 year old!

Comment: @AlecTeal No worries, I can read that perfectly fine. So it seems that $i)$ is correct and my assumption on $\vec{\phi}$ seems to be right too, at least for $i)$. The only thing left is what I did wrong on the vector way to calculate the area in $i)$... weird I'll try again later.
Also I'm still in a little doubt if $\vec{\phi}$is right (in $ii)$), since these task did always make alot of sense and were nicely computable (I'm in 3rd semester right now) and after trying a bit and consulting WolframAlpha and similar sites $\sqrt{\sin^2 x + 1}$ seems to have no satisfying solution.

Comment: Did you get the question from a source you can email? Also @L1me remember what I said about phi-with-an-arrow-over it looking like a vector field, integrating over a surface with a vector field on it (to work out flux (Latin: Flow)) is not a different procedure, there Flux = $\iint\phi.\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\|dA$ note that I want to put an arrow over my phi, but I don't know how. A vector field is different to a vector-valued-function because a vecfield is associating a direction with each point. You are not doing this. You are associating points

Comment: @L1me explicitly that integral would be $\phi(f(u,v))$ BTW, a lot of these short notations use "you can work out what I mean as it'd make no sense otherwise" logic.

Comment: @AlecTeal Why would you want that paper where the task is given, also there is no need for that since I copied all given things here, there is no advantage from looking at that task sheet. Also I was taught that the \ vec {} (<- Latex notation) is there to indicate that your variable has multiple components, and not that it's a vector field, you said that the arrow is reserved here but I think that's more personal preference than a rule. I'll keep the arrows to indicate multiple components, also a vector field is a vector valued function too. It's a function assigning a direction to points.

Comment: @L1me books can have typos, assignments or lecture notes have authors you can email and say "Hello there, I'm a student of yours and I'm really struggling with X, I've asked others and they're stuck too" also notation will change, and no you are not assigning a direction to points. A parametisation is not a vector field, trust me on this, it'll become clearer as you go further (manifolds is where this notation shines) - I would not mislead you.